# Docker container run exits immediately when mounting paths

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I am running docker on windows 10. When I run this command without the `-v` flag to mount the host drive and file path to the container path, then the container runs fine and I can connect to it. However, when I provide the flag to mount the paths the container exits immediately. This is my command which runs without any error

```
docker container run -v c:/container-fs:/usr/src/app --publish 8001:8080 --detach --name bboard-ubuntu bulletinboard:Ubuntu
```

when I run the command `docker container ls --all`, I see that the container named `bboard-ubuntu` has exited almost immediately after it started up.

When trying to exec into the container using the command `docker exec -it bboard-ubuntu /bin/bash`, I get the error message as below:

> Error response from daemon: Container
>   26a2d3361dfc0c890xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx97be532ab6e8771652e5b is not running

When I remove the mount flags and run it like this below, there are no issues and I can `exec` into the container file system.

```
docker container run --publish 8001:8080 --detach --name bboard-ubuntu bulletinboard:Ubuntu
```

How do I trace and fix this issue caused by providing the mount flag?

**Edit**
This is the Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json .

# replace shell with bash so we can source files
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl \
    && apt-get -y autoclean
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils
RUN apt-get -y install nano

# nvm environment variables
ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION 13.9.0

# install nvm
# https://github.com/creationix/nvm#install-script
RUN curl --silent -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.2/install.sh | bash

# install node and npm
RUN source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm use default

# add node and npm to path so the commands are available
ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH

# confirm installation
RUN node -v
RUN npm -v

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]

COPY . .
```

Here is the error after removing detach

> npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! syscall open npm ERR! path
>   /usr/src/app/package.json npm ERR! errno -2 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no
>   such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/package.json' npm ERR!
>   enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file. npm ERR!
>   enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /root/.npm/_logs/2020-02-26T19_02_33_143Z-debug.log

I am running these commands on windows host. Where do I find the `/root/.npm/` log folder?

Comment: Try https://forums.docker.com/t/volume-mounts-in-windows-does-not-work/10693/160 to reset credentials for the host drive.

Comment: Without seeing the image `Dockerfile`, it looks like you're overwriting the application source code from the image with whatever random content you have on your host, which could cause all sorts of problems (including the dreaded line-ending conversion issue).  Your first step should probably be to run this without `--detach` and see what log messages it's actually printing out.

Comment: @DavidMaze I ran without detach and updated the question. Im not unable to figure out why the copy of the package.json is not happening there. As per this document for a Node base image it should, right? https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/ I have only changed the base image to ubuntu so I try out installation of Node on a different base image.

Comment: Your `docker run -v` option is overwriting the `package.json` file and other things installed in the Dockerfile with content from your host.  There’s no “merge” operation, the entire `/usr/src/app` tree is hidden.

Comment: What would be the fix then? The copy from current folder also has the same package.json file. Im new to docker so probably missing aomething in the order of how things needs to be executed. Also the reason for the -v is to access the dockerized file system from the host

Comment: @DavidMaze I ran a very basic dockerfile build command which had the very basic instructions FROM ubuntu:18.04

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 8080
  .....and even this exited without an error even in detached mode.